# FloatingActionButton Rendering: Color value '?attr/colorAccent' must start with #

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-appcompat, floating-action-button

I can't seem to be able to get the FAB working in my app (with Android Studio). I see the following when I try to build

```
Exception raised during rendering: Color value '?attr/colorAccent' must start with #
```

This started happening once I mucked around a little with app themes, so I probably broke something there, but I don't know what... Here's what I have:

**app/build.gradle**:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "us.daybreakinnovations.push"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'

**values/styles.xml**:

```
<style name="AppCompatTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorStatusBar</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorNavigationBar</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppCompatTheme"/>
```

values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppMaterialLightDarkTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorStatusBar</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorNavigationBar</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppMaterialLightDarkTheme"/>
```

(The colors are all defined in `values/colors.xml`)

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

Did I not define my themes correctly? I figured the way this was going to work is, the `AndroidManifest` will look for the `AppTheme` style - which is the parent of a `MaterialLightDarkActionBar` for API21+ and `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` for lower. Maybe this is not what I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IN your `res/values.xml` you have to remove the android namespace because you are using an AppCompat theme.

```
<style name="AppCompatTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: And this solves it. I am not quite sure how this inheritance works, but I'll get around to figuring it out eventually...

Answer (score 0):

Check if the colors you use all begin with a #

Comment: They all do. I have a couple that reference @android:color/black, but that shouldn't be a problem.